# Google Anymote Protocol - How to send characters without keycodes

Tags: google-tv

I am attempting to build an on screen keyboard for Google TV using the [Anymote](https://developers.google.com/tv/remote/docs/anymote) protocol. Sending keys listed here works fine:

http://code.google.com/p/anymote-protocol/source/browse/proto/keycodes.proto

How can I send keys without keycodes like an **ampersand**? On the Google TV remote, I hit the left shift then @. Is it possible to emulate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the Data event: https://developers.google.com/tv/remote/docs/anymote